# ARCore: Get a Pose's location/perspective relative to another Pose

Tags: java, android, matrix, arcore

When I get a face's center Pose, its always relative to the camera. I'd like to get the Pose's location and orientation as relative to an origin Pose instead.

Here's what I've tried:

```
    Pose centerPose = face.getCenterPose();
    // set up origin neutral Pose if not done yet
    if (neutralPose == null) {
      neutralPose = centerPose;
    }
    centerPose = centerPose.compose(neutralPose.inverse());
```

But this is not giving me what I want - rotating the head results in major positional translations.

Using ARCore's Pose (or Anchor?), how would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I was close! The magic words are:

```
    Pose relativePose = neutralPose.inverse().compose(centerPose);
```

This gives me what I want. The reason being: I need the neutral's inverse to transform the new position BACK.